# Dynamically pick up files from folder for export

Tags: javascript

Hi (I am a DB Guy with 0 idea on JS),
I have following folder structure
Customers---> Daily Reports in PDF

E.g. Customer A --> Report 1st Oct, Report 2nd Oct
Customer B --> Report 1st Oct, Report 2nd Oct

When above customers login to a portal we are planning to give a button clicking on which the PDF files in folder will be downloaded into their laptop/desktop.

So expected User Flow

Users logs into Portal --> Views Charts --> Clicks on download button --> Web App identifies who the customer is and picks up corresponding PDF Reports --> PDF is downloaded into customers laptop.. Can this be handled from Web application side?